# Cant use Appbar with Buttons

Tags: java, android, appbar

I started working with the Holo Theme, and I want to build my app with this Theme (without using the Compact)

The problem is that my App bar is whithout the Buttons. (I cannot use the ifRoom option for showing the menus icons).

my menu code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="105"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_edit"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
    android:orderInCategory="110"
    android:title="@string/action_edit"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

and my Java Class:

```
package myfirsttry.another;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "linir.key";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, secondActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etInput);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using the Holo Theme rather than [AppCompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat)? Your app will crash on <APi 11 devices and look totally out of places on API21+ devices - problems (among others) that you won't have if you use AppCompat.

Answer (score 0):

The `app:showAsAction` is only applicable if you use [AppCompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) as is strongly recommended for compatibility and consistency across all API levels.

If you'd like to only use the system provided action bar, then you'd replace all instances of `app:showAsAction` with `android:showAsAction`.

Comment: Thanks man! I feel so stupid XD. at first I got an error but it still workes! thanks again

Comment: If this helped answer your question, make sure you accept the answer to remove it from the unanswered queue. Glad you got it working!